# Unable move Raltek USB wifi equipment to master mode on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I try to set "master mode" for USB wifi chip and get error.
I use Ubuntu 12.04.1

This is information about device:

lsmod:

```
rtl8192cu              97722  0 
rtl8192c_common        69519  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                95804  1 rtl8192cu
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN
```

iwconfig:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

When I call iwconfig for set master mode, I have error:

```
user@comp-name:~$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode master
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

This is output of /var/log/kern.log:

```
 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.704738] rtl8192cu: MAC address: 00:1d:1a:0e:cf:37
  2 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.704745] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
  3 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742213] rtlwifi: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
  4 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742220] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz
  5 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742224] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
  6 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742227] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz
  7 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742230] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
  8 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742233] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz 
  9 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742236] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 10 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742238] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz 
 11 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742241] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 12 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742244] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz 
 13 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742247] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 14 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742249] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz 
 15 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742252] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 16 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742255] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz 
 17 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742258] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 18 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742260] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz 
 19 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742263] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 20 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742266] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz 
 21 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742269] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 22 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742271] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz 
 23 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742274] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 24 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742277] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz 
 25 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742280] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/
 26 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742282] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz as custom regd has 
 27 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742285] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz as custom regd has 
 28 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742287] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz as custom regd has 
 29 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.742437] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core sin
 30 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.754342] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC0040000
 31 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.754346] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
 32 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.754348] [drm] size 3145728
 33 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.754350] [drm] fb depth is 24
 34 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.754352] [drm]    pitch is 4096
 35 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.754574] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
 36 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.755882] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x
 37 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.755958] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
 38 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.755960] drm: registered panic notifier
 39 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.760483] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.12.0 20080528 for 0000:01:
 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.847769] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_
 41 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.848459] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
 42 Oct 15 14:26:32 comp-name kernel: [   12.888198] init: lightdm main process (1031) killed by TERM sign
 43 Oct 15 14:26:33 comp-name kernel: [   13.860359] i2c i2c-3: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
 44 Oct 15 14:26:33 comp-name kernel: [   13.862312] [drm:radeon_vga_detect] *ERROR* VGA-1: probed a monit
 45 Oct 15 14:26:33 comp-name kernel: [   14.025160] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
```

Any ideas?
If I will use madwifi driver, can it solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitor (AP) or "master" mode is not supported by the rtl* family of drivers, with the exception of rtl8187 as seen [here](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers).

[madwifi](http://madwifi-project.org/) has been deprecated by the ath5k and ath9k modules, which are targeted at Atheros and not RealTek chips.

Comment: I would say the situation is the same also for `rtl8187` driver from mainline, so your statement is not completely true, unless you use [rtl8187 ieee80211-based driver](https://github.com/Dekadencee/rtl8187-Linux-Driver/tree/master/). I've made small investigation on the subject, see my findings [here](http://centurion.nfors.com/w/software/linux#does_realtek_rtl8187_support_master_mode).